# Checking for nil in an EKCalendar

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, eventkit, ekeventstore

I'm working on an app that gets events from a specific iOS calendar. When that calendar is empty however I, of course, get a fatal nil error.

```
let calendar = calendarWithTitle("Personal Trainer's Tool",
            type: EKCalendarTypeCalDAV,
            source: icloudSource!,
            eventType: EKEntityTypeEvent)

/* Create the predicate that we can later pass to the event store in order to fetch the events */
        let searchPredicate = eventStore.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(
            startDate,
            endDate: endDate,
            calendars: [calendar!])

/* Fetch all the events that fall between the starting and the ending dates */
        events = eventStore.eventsMatchingPredicate(searchPredicate) as [EKEvent] //Error on this line


if events.count == 0 {
                println("No events could be found")
            } else {

                // Go through all the events and print them to the console
                for event in events{
                    println("Event title = \(event.title)")
                    println("Event start date = \(event.startDate)")
                    println("Event end date = \(event.endDate)")
                }
            }
```

the 'calendar' in my searchPredicate is an EKCalendar as it should be, but I don't know how to check if it's empty before allowing the searchPredicate to execute to avoid the fatal error. Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use optional binding:

```
let calendar = calendarWithTitle("Personal Trainer's Tool",
    type: EKCalendarTypeCalDAV,
    source: icloudSource!,
    eventType: EKEntityTypeEvent)

/* Create the predicate that we can later pass to the event store in order to fetch the events */
let searchPredicate = eventStore.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(
    startDate,
    endDate: endDate,
    calendars: [calendar!])

/* Fetch all the events that fall between the starting and the ending dates */
if let events = eventStore.eventsMatchingPredicate(searchPredicate) as? [EKEvent] {


    if events.count == 0 {
        println("No events could be found")
    } else {

        // Go through all the events and print them to the console
        for event in events{
            println("Event title = \(event.title)")
            println("Event start date = \(event.startDate)")
            println("Event end date = \(event.endDate)")
        }
    }
}
```